# Specific usage of the word "Cruise" on a song

Tags: meaning, american-english, songs

i just wanted to ask about the word "Cruise", because on the song by "Florida Georgia Line", they say "You make me wanna roll my windows down and CRUISE" and I don't understand the specific meaning of that word. Thank you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruising_(driving)):

> Cruising is a social activity that primarily consists of driving a car.  Cruising can be an expression of the freedom of possessing a driver's license. 
>    Cruising is distinguished from regular driving by the social and recreational nature of the activity, which is characterized by an impulsively random, often aimless course.  A popular route (or "strip") is often the focus of cruising.  "Cruise nights" are evenings during which cars drive slowly.

Basically, to cruise, in this context, is to drive slowly so as to see and be seen.  It gives pedestrians and other drivers a chance to admire your vehicle and give you recognition for its "coolness".  There are or can be other factors and motivations, but that's pretty much it.

Edit:  Here is some [more info about cruising](http://www.caranddriver.com/features/the-end-of-cruising) and how cities (in the US) are (or were in 2004) trying to stop it.

Comment: Feel free to upvote or even accept this answer, if it answers your question.

Comment: I've downvoted, as it condones questions lacking basic / reasonable research.